# jQuery - open new window on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I open a new browser window on page load w/ jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: i love how this question doesnt have a javascript tag or even mention javascript. jquery is the language of the dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in the jQuery `document.ready` event (shortcut'ed below) by calling the `window.open()` method

```
$(function(){ 
    window.open(url, windowName[, windowFeatures]); 
});
```

**windowFeatures:**

- **status**    The status bar at the bottom of the window.
- **toolbar**   The standard browser toolbar, with buttons such as Back and Forward.
- **location**  The Location entry field where you enter the URL.
- **menubar**   The menu bar of the window
- **directories**   The standard browser directory buttons, such as What’s New and What’s Cool
- **resizable** Allow/Disallow the user to resize the window.
- **scrollbars**    Enable the scrollbars if the document is bigger than the window
- **height**    Specifies the height of the window in pixels. (example: height=’350′)
- **width** Specifies the width of the window in pixels.

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml